# APK size increased after integrating admob , how much expected?

Tags: android, admob, apk

I have integrated admob in my small apps and i am observing an apk size increase of 1 mb, is it normal? or can i reduce it further. Following are the things i did while integrating the admob.

**Apk size increased from 1,791 kb to 2,677 kb**

**1)** Added dependencies which are only required

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

**2)** Added proguard lines

```
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.ads.** { public *; }

-keep public class com.google.ads.** { public *; }
```

Is there anything else i can do to reduce it further, from your experiance how much increase is normal?

Comment: Use firebase ads dependency instead and with 'minifyEnabled true' apply 'shrinkResources true' as well. you will feel a noticeable difference in apk size. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**You need to add these in your gradle.build file**

```
buildTypes {
debug {
    minifyEnabled true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard.txt'
}
release {
    minifyEnabled true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard.txt'
}
...
}
```

Comment: delete the fileTree dependency, you are already adding it with the other dependency

Comment: No that is for some library jar file that i use for vungle ads.

Comment: try reading stuff here...may help you reduce some bytes http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html

Answer (score 0):

An **approximate increase of 1 to 2 mb** is noticed. Will be more when you add other network sdks later (if you do).

**Be careful with proguard when using ad networks** and test it thoroughly with all ad types (text, image and videos) - (banner, interstitial and other types). Sometimes there are issues with a particular type which we think would work fine because one type worked when debugging.

Comment: I have only banner ads and our apps are small live wallpapers so even a 1 mb increase really counts.

Comment: yes, but that much you will need to do with in order for the ad network to work properly. you can experiment with proguard to remove more classes for types other than banner. Currently you are retaining all public classes. But that is risky as i said. Still, worth a shot if you have enough time.

Comment: For this you'll need to check the play services source code and figure out what classes the banner ad will really really need.

Comment: Google Play Services (AdMob) ships with a proguard config now so you shouldn't add anything. You can also try adding `shrinkResources = true` to try and slim down the APK size.